# Prevent blank row being added on the datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a datagrid,in which I want to disable new rows being created at the bottom, when the user clicks on any cell on the datagrid. I only want the default behaviour,add blank row at bottom when the enter key is pressed.

Here is my Datagrid :

```
 <custom:CustomDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                           AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                           RowHeight="27"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
                           RowHeaderWidth="30"
                           CanUserAddRows="true">
        <custom:CustomDataGrid.Columns>
            <custom:CustomDataGridTextColumn  Header="Product Name"
                                              Binding="{Binding ProductName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                              Width="250" />
            <custom:CustomDataGridTextColumn  Header="Unit Price"
                                              Binding="{Binding UnitPrice,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                              Width="130" />
            <custom:CustomDataGridTextColumn  Header="Qty"
                                              Binding="{Binding Quantity,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                              Width="130" />
            <custom:CustomDataGridTextColumn  Header="Amount"
                                              Binding="{Binding Amount,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                              Width="130"
                                              IsLastEditableColumn="True" />
        </custom:CustomDataGrid.Columns>
    </custom:CustomDataGrid>
```

How do I prevent blank row being added to the datagrid when the user select other cells on the datagrid

Comment: You set datagrid prop CanUserAddRows="true", maybe you should try CanUserAddRows="False"

Comment: @Den ,If I set the CanUserAddRows="False" ,I cant add blank row when enter key is press

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the blank row being added you can set the property `CanUserAddRows` on the `DataGrid` to false.

To still be able to add rows you can handle one of the key events (eg `KeyDown` etc) to add an empty/default product to `Items` and set focus to the first editable column in the new item when the Enter key is pressed.

Comment: add an empty product to items is ok when enter key is pressed,but how do I set the first column editable of the new row

Comment: A simple google search gives me http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/11/08/how-to-programmatically-select-and-focus-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid-in-wpf/ and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/89df8b8f-29b8-4915-b2b6-e153e05f9ca9/how-to-programmatically-select-and-focus-a-cell-in-the-new-wpf-datagrid?forum=wpf which looks like it will help you with that. If not, look around on SO or ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `IsReadOnly="True"` in the DataGrid XAML.

Comment: ,doing so I cant Edit the cells anymore,all cells are turned to be readonly